# rubik's cube solutions not possible

Tags: combinatorics

You are given a Rubik's cube having no colored stickers on its sides.  You can apply the proper ones in such a way that the puzzle canNOT be solved.  In how many ways can you do this?  Is this puzzle itself UNsovable?

Comment: One obvious possibility is to put two stickers of the same color in the middle square on opposite sides of the cube.  Or two stickers of the same color on a corner.

Comment: Instead of trying to compute this directly, I am sure someone has already figured out how many possible positions there are for a Rubik's cube that *is* solvable ... so subtract that number from the number of ways you can put the stickers on in any way. Still not an easy problem, with all the symmetries and such, but that should be doable, and certainly solvable.

Comment: For those who enjoy programming during the Christmas holidays, then this is ideal to find the exact number requested. The positions leading to a solution is one think, all the paths leading to them is another.

Comment: I think you found something to do for your Christmas holidays!

Comment: And deprive others of the fun????

Answer (score 2):

A Rubik's cube has 6 center cubelets, 8 corner cubelets, and 12 edge cubelets. The 6 center cubelets have a fixed relationship with respect to each other. Each edge cubelet can be one of two orientations, while each corner cubelet can be in one of three orientations.

If one disassembles the cube (leaving the face stickers alone) and reassembles it at random, there are therefore $2^{12}3^88!12!$ ways of doing so. However, for solvable positions, the combined edge orientation must be the identity, the combined corner orientation must be the identity, and the overall permutation of edges and corners must be even. This means that half of the edge orientations are impossible, two-thirds of the corner orientations are impossible, and half of the cubelet permutations are impossible. Thus the number of solvable positions of the cube is $$\frac{2^{12}3^88!12!}{2\cdot 3\cdot 2} = 2^{10}3^78!12! = 43,252,003,274,489,856,000.$$

On the other hand, if one considers all 54 stickers to be distinguishable, there would be $54!$ ways of placing them on the cube (for a cube in a fixed orientation). However, the stickers actually come in six groups of 9, each group of which are indistinguishable, allowing them to be rearranged freely within the group. Which means there are actually $\frac{54!}{(9!)^6}$
ways of placing the stickers. But the calculation of solvable positions was not based on an orientation of the cube. Hence we should also divide this number by the 24 possible orientations of the cube. So there are 
$$\frac{54!}{24(9!)^6} = 4,212,390,092,651,019,262,132,517,598,730,500,000$$ways of applying the stickers.

Therefore, there are $$\frac{54!}{24(9!)^6} - 2^{10}3^78!12! = 4,212,390,092,651,019,218,880,514,324,240,644,000$$
ways of placing the stickers that will leave the cube unsolvable.

Comment: One notes that the first sixteen digits are the same for solvable versus unsolvable.  That means that at the factory there's about a 50-50 chance that the low-paid workers placing the colored stickers on the sides could make a mistake.  It must be frustrating to buy a cube with an UNsolvable configuration of the stickers.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot - if they were putting the stickers on at random, that means there is a 99.99999999999999% chance that they would leave it in an unsolvable configuration, not 50%. However, they don't put the stickers on at random. They make all the stickers on one side the same color. Then - assuming they use all 6 colors - there is a 100% chance that they will leave the cube in a solvable position.

Comment: I  still say that it would be 50% since in solvable or UNsolvable configurations both have the stickers placed randomly.  If you've ever worked at a Rubik's factory, you'd notice that the stickers are put on at random since the pay is so low--paying attention  would be worth more wages per hour.  The puzzle would be more of a challenge if instead of the six colors the 54 squares were numbered 1 to 54 in order 1 to 9 on one face, 10 to 18 on another, 19 to 27 on the next and so on.  Twist it to get a jumble of numbers, then begin to return it to the original numerical order.

Comment: You disassembled the Rubik's cube, but I made no mention of doing this. If the stickers were placed at random, why would the cube NOT be solvable? It can still be altered many, many ways to eventually arrive at a solution, can it not?  One would have to experiment by removing the stickers from a solved cube, then randomly placing them back on the six sides, then trying to solve it.  Do NOT take the cube apart!

Comment: It is quite clear that *you* have never worked in a Rubik's factory. In fact, your naive interpretation makes it doubtful you have ever worked in manufacturing at all. Rest assured that any business run as per your description would quickly go bankrupt.Your idea of replacing colors with numbers would not increase the difficulty at all - except in making it harder to spot the pieces you need to place. (If you also demand the numbers all line up the same orientation, then you also add the difficulty of turning the center facelets to the right alignment - but this is a known variation.)

Comment: The discussion of disassembling the cube is the standard approach for calculating how many solvable cube positions exist. You can find result worked up in numerous places, including wikipedia. Since (unsolvable positions) = (all positions) - (solvable positions), it is the obvious way to calculate the number of unsolvable positions as you asked. Please reread the post and think carefully about it sometime when you are sober.

Comment: It could be that we are not talking about the same subject.  It could also be that you have little sense of humor about the discussion at the imaginary

Comment: It could be that we are not talking about the same subject.  It could also be that you have little sense of humor about the discussion at the imaginary Rubik's factory.  If each face of all the same colors (a solved cube) had the numbers 1 to 3, 4 to 6, and 7 to 9 printed in three rows, then scrambled, and then manipulated back into a solved cube, would these nine numbers per face HAVE to ALWAYS be in the original order for the cube to be solved?

Comment: Cancel my 50-50 chances after a closer reading of UNsolvable conditions. Such are the hazards of all the noise in a public library where I send e-mails.

Comment: Yes, If you just drew the numbers on a standard colored cube, and ignored them as you solved the cube in the ordinary way, you would find at the end the numbers would always be in exactly the right order, and all but the $5$ in the center would be in the same orientation. The $5$ could be twisted in any direction. (But there is a known technique for rotating it into the correct orientation as well while leaving the rest of the cube unchanged.)

Comment: This is because the movable parts of the cube are actually the 8 corner and 12 edge cubelets, not the facelets that form their sides. The centers also rotate, but do not change locations. These cubelets are each unique. There is only one way that they fit together to make a solved cube.

Comment: Again number all faces from 1 to 9 on a solved cube.  Manipulate until you reach all presolved positions of all successes.  You now will have a file of all distinct presolved configurations of all six faces; consult this file to insure that you are not trying to solve an UNsolvable puzzle because some evil person switched some of the colored stickers.  Since there are many, many more UNsolvable positions, how could you test after a certain number of moves that you DO have an UNsovable puzzle in your hands?  Is there a finite number of steps in a trial and error test?

Comment: Use any of the many known algorithms to solve the cube. If the cube is is unsolvable because of illegal manipulations, at some point, the algorithm can no longer be followed. Since these algorithms are finite in length, you will quickly have your answer (I once calculated that the algorithm I was using at the time required at most 189 quarter-turns, and there are much more efficient ones than it). I have some experience with this as my father often moved stickers around on our cube, and regularly put it in unsolvable configurations.

Comment: More particularly - look first that all 6 centers are different colors. If so, determine the antipodal color-pairs (each pair are the colors on centers that are directly opposite each other on the cube). Next count that every color is used exactly 9 times. Then make sure that each cubelet has all colors on it distinct and non-antipodal. Then look at the corners and make sure that the color ordering on them matches the color ordering of the corresponding centers. If all these hold, the cube can be "solved" by disassembly and reassembly of the cubelets.

Comment: Machine is screaming go to discussion = too confusing for me.  E-mail makes more sense = thekingfishb@yahoo.ca.  Check this on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=computer+solves+rubik%27s+cube+in+1+second

Comment: That still leaves the three conditions I described in my answer: total corner orientation is the identity, total edge orientation is the identity, and cubelet permutation is even. All of these can be tested without solving the cube, but it is complicated to do so. Far easier just to attempt solving, and discover if you are stuck with just two pieces exchanged, or just one piece in the wrong orientation. Those cannot be accomplished by legal moves.

Comment: The challenge is to redesign the mechanics so their are MORE possible  paths to a success.  Also think about a four-dimensional cube.